# Filtering (search) a model with multiple params in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This function in my `Profile` model receive a hash from a search form and should filter the table depending on those values. I guess there is something like a pattern for such a standard behavior, right now I ended up with this (unfortunately I had to reproduce the code here, so it might not work for some reasons, but you get the idea).

Just a note: we're storing in the model some strings containing multiple data, each of these fields should be a one-to-many relationship (db normality violation). I give an example: `country_preferences` is a string filled up by an html `select :multiple => true`. In the string I then find values like: `["Australia", "China", "United Kingdom"]`.

```
  def search opts # This default doesn't work the way I would like = {:user_type => :family}

    #TODO: default opts value in method sign if possible
    opts[:user_type] ||= :family

    # initial criteria
    fields= "user_type= ?"
    values= [opts[:user_type]]

    # each field filters the list in one of these three ways
    staight_fields = [ :country, :first_name, :last_name, :nationality ]
    like_fields = [:country_preferences, :keyword, :languages ]
    bool_fields = [:driver, :housework, :children ]

    # cicle the options and build the query    
    opts.each do |k, v|
      if straight_fields.include? k
        fields += " AND #{k} = ?"
        values += v
      elsif like_fields.include? k
        fields += " AND #{k} like %?%"
        values += v
      elsif bool_fields.include? k
        fields += " AND #{k} = ?"
        values += v == 'true'
      else
        logger.warn "opts #{k} with value #{v} ignored from search"
      end
    end

    # execute the query and return the result
    self.registered.actives.where([fields] + values)   
  end
```

I think I can use more `scope` but how can I combine them together? In general, how can I make this code much better?

The boss, when introducing the project, said one-to-many relationships for that kind of fields would be a pain in the back. What do you think about this pragmatic solution?

Comment: Does the code you posted in your edit actually work? It seems like you're missing `profiles =` at the beginning of every line after the first and a final `profiles` at the end of the method.

Comment: Good point! - I've already corrected my code and I'm not going to refactor, but that behavior (getting rid of all the assignment) can be achieved with a **dynamic delegator** explained by Ryan Bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/212-refactoring-dynamic-delegator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked into using a pre existing gem for this? I found one called [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) that seems like it might do exactly what you're trying to refactor. You would need to add a scope for each of your filters and then add some `has_scope` calls in your controller.

Here's a few examples. I'm not as familiar with Rails 3 scopes as I am with 2, so the code likely won't work as is.

Model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :country, lambda {|country| where(:country => country) }
  scope :keyword, lambda {|keyword| where(["keyword LIKE :term", {:term => "%#{keyword}%"}]) }
  scope :driver, where{:driver => true)
end
```

Controller:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  has_scope :country
  has_scope :keyword
  has_scope :driver, :type => :boolean
end
```

Comment: this plugin looks easy tiny and tested, I would avoid to install an external plugin to substitute a single function used once, but when I have some time I'm going to dive in the code, there should be something to learn, thanks

Comment: thanks a lot, that was it, but you don't need to declare scopes like country or driver, as you can see in the question edit you have by default scoped_by_driver(true) that works the same.

Comment: I didn't even know about the scoped_by_* methods, great tip!